# При выполнении функции Promise pending

Tags: javascript, promise

Почему при вызове функции Promise Pending?

```
const API_KEY = "76876876";

const API_URL_POPULAR =
"https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.2/films/top?type=TOP_100_POPULAR_FILMS&page=2";

const API_URL_SEARCH = 
"https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.1/films/search-by-keyword?keyword="


async function getMovies(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": API_KEY,
    },
  });
  const respData = await resp.json();
  return respData.films[1].nameRu;
}


let z = getMovies(API_URL_POPULAR)

console.log(z);  //Promise {<pending>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Асинхронная функция `getMovies` возвращает Promise.

Для того чтобы вывести результат, его нужно дождаться. Например, так:

```
async function getMovies(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": API_KEY,
    },
  });
  const respData = await resp.json();
  return respData.films[1].nameRu;
}



getMovies(API_URL_POPULAR)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как потом этот res использовать? Как его можно присвоить перемнной?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. В примере выше результат фетча находится в переменной `res`. Дальше уже можно использовать как угодно.